# Error when trying to convert mp3 with image to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

The mp3 has an image in it, maybe some album images. When I use ffmpeg to convert it to mp4, it goes wrong. But if I convert an mp3 without an image, it succeeds.

My command is like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.mp4
```

Here's the error:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Here is all the console output:

```
ellodeiMac:mine ello$ ffmpeg -frames 0 -i 4.mp3 -y test.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.11.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct 24 2012 12:21:13 with llvm_gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
  configuration: --disable-yasm
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fa12301ae00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
Input #0, mp3, from '4.mp3':
  Metadata:
    artist          : 贵族乐团
    album           : 美声天籁
    title           : 肖邦离别曲
    Tagging time    : 2012-09-18T08:12:10
  Duration: 00:04:01.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 240x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : e
      comment         : Cover (front)
[buffer @ 0x109115780] w:240 h:240 pixfmt:yuvj420p tb:1/90000 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[buffersink @ 0x109133720] No opaque field provided
[format @ 0x1091338e0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'format'
[scale @ 0x109133bc0] w:240 h:240 fmt:yuvj420p sar:1/1 -> w:240 h:240 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 flags:0x4
[mp4 @ 0x7fa123035c00] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[aformat @ 0x109136ec0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'aformat'
[aresample @ 0x1091370c0] chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:44100Hz -> chl:stereo fmt:flt r:44100Hz
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fa12303be00] timebase 1/90000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum 
admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    artist          : 贵族乐团
    album           : 美声天籁
    title           : 肖邦离别曲
    Tagging time    : 2012-09-18T08:12:10
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 240x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : e
      comment         : Cover (front)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Try to drop video encoding (perhaps -vn or -frames:0 would do? The image is most probably of size 300x300, which doesn't conform to mpeg4 specification IIRC.

Comment: Just a guess, but clever enough program should be able to "guess" from the line `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.m4a` that only audio stream is expected. Though the program can be clever enough to ignore the extensions and trying to analyze all the streams contained in the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-vn` to remove the video stream.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -vn output.mp4
```